# Setting column on empty dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm reading json arrays from a text file and then create an empty dataframe. I want to add a new column 'id' to the empty dataframe. 'id' comes from the json arrays in the text file.

Error message reads "Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that canot be converted to a series". I tried to overcome this error by defining dataframe size upfront which did not help. Any ideas?

```
import json
import pandas as pd

path = 'my/path'
mydata = []
myfile = open(path, "r")

for line in myfile:
    try:
        myline = json.loads(line)
        mydata.append(myline)
    except:
        continue

mydf = pd.DataFrame()
mydf['id'] = map(lambda myline: myline['id'], mydata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better is use:

```
for line in myfile:
    try:
        #extract only id to list
        myline = json.loads(line)['id']
        mydata.append(myline)
    except:
        continue

print (mydata)
[10, 5]

#create DataFrame by constructor
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'id':mydata})
print (mydf)
   id
0  10
1   5
```

Comment: Blanket `except` statements should almost always be avoided